# (Advanced Issue) Any way I can recreate this game's 3D texture effect?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

[image: .]

I'm trying to recreate this 3d effect, but I'm not sure how they did it, and I was hoping I can find something here. It even follows the animation it does. To me it looks like it was either duplicated and moved, or they made the material be reflected by the visor. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way to do this would be to have a *Principled BSDF* with a quite dark *Base Color* and *Transmission* set to 1, to have a dark glass material. Then add a *Solidify* modifier on the helmet. The red glowing parts with a high emission would then be on the outside as well as on the inner faces from the solidification and shine through the dark glass, maybe a bit blurred from *Transmission Roughness* in the *Principled BSDF*.

These are my materials, the glass on the left and the glow on the right. Of course you could do this in one material with masking and a *Mix Shader*, for simplicity I just added different materials to different faces. For the red glow I also used a *Principled BSDF* instead of an *Emission* shader because the original helmet is a bit reflective in the glowing parts, too.

[image: materials]

And this is the result with a little bit of glow added in the *Compositor*, the *Thickness* setting in the *Solidify* modifier determines how strong or deep the 3D effect is:

[image: helmet]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried doing what you suggested, but when I add a solidify modifier on the helmet, it creates this weird effect instead the 3d depth to it. imgur.com/JPISC9o

Comment: @WolfStix The "weird effect" is when you're generating the thickness to the outside and especially very much thickness. Also it looks like some face normals are inverted since some are going inside, some outside. Also, it is much weirder if you make it _very_ thick. I just used a subtle thickness, well, like a sheet of glass and not a massive wall  And of course the more complex the shape, the more problems you can get with overlapping and strange corners if you extend to far.

Comment: You mind if I give you the blend file and see what you can do to add this effect? This model is much different than the one you shown in your screenshot since this is actually a character from the game.

Comment: Sure, I'll have a look tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. I'll link it so you can go on it whenever you need. Lmk if you're finished checking it out. https://mega.nz/file/pg1ExCzS#irW3jiojcox1X-g_E7-bXnDy2OWEE0LujwfwB0meHYA

Comment: @WolfStix Okay, so I looked at the file and there are a lot of problems. I didn't know this is all one big mesh. This means, everything gets solidified, so it would be better to restrict the solidify to a vertex group, this could be "head". Or you create a new one which contains only the glass parts. No matter how, this creates non-manifold geometry at the transition between solidified and non-solidified faces which can mess up the smooth shading. By the way, a _Thickness_ of 0.001 is absolutely sufficient according to the size of the model, maybe only 0.0005

Comment: @WolfStix The other thing is, I tried to read this big confusing custom shader node group and look at the textures - the problem with them is, there is no glass part, it's just glossy black (since the helmet wasn't supposed to be looked through, I guess). However, without transmissive parts the inside generated by the _Solidify_ modifier will not show on the outside. So the materials need to be reworked to contain a transmissive part. But I'm sorry, there are so many textures and custom node groups mixed together that I didn't want to go through all to find which ones I have to change.

Comment: Oh, there is another possibility without the necessity of glass and a _Solidify_ modifier. But this is quite complex and too long for an answer I guess and it might still be problematic with the complete helmet material in one piece. So I'll just leave a link to the tutorial here, this is more as an information on  what is possible with materials. Erindale Woodford created this tutorial for CG Masters: [Procedural Parallax Effect in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XS2TJfn1TAg)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138249/discussion-between-wolfstix-and-gordon-brinkmann).

Comment: Do you have discord? I'm trying to figure this for something I'm making. You're the closest I'm getting to making this effect. I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: @WolfStix I'm sorry but I'm not on discord.

Comment: Alright here's what I did. I simplified the custom shader node to a Principled BSDF. The other node group I use is to make the texture animations like how the game does itself. It creates a visor animation. https://imgur.com/a/TKEHLrz Hope this helps making it more possible to create the 3d effect.

Comment: I'm not supposed to rework the complete material for you... or am I? As I said, for my solution the dark part has to be a dark glass (i.e transmissive) so that the emission from the inner wall generated by the _Solidify_ modifier can be seen through it.

Comment: No no sorry, I meant I hope it helps giving instruction. I do really appreciate the time your making to help me. Even if I can't do this effect right, thanks for helping. But I honestly just don't know what to do. The red glow is a texture for the visor so it can't really pop out. I've tried your solutions, I've made the black glossy, and mixed the glow. And again, the solidify just doesn't act right. https://imgur.com/a/FaL3J3n

Comment: You've made the black glossy, but glossy is not equal to glass: glass needs transmission to look through. You have to make the glass part transmissive - and then it can be completely black for than you can't see through it either. The other thing I already mentioned is, you should limit the Solidify to a vertex group which contains only the glass part -better  would be to make the glass a separate piece. And your image looks as if your Solidify has a much too high thickness. As I said above, something like 0.001 or even half of that is enough.

Comment: In the picture that you provided earlier, is the red emission part a mesh? Because if I make the visor glass like, that makes my emission also glass like since it's part of the glass. The red glow is a emission texture.

Comment: @WolfStix Yes, it is part of the mesh. Please just read my answer thoroughly: _"These are my materials, the glass on the left and the glow on the right. Of course you could do this in one material with masking and a Mix Shader, for simplicity I just added different materials to different faces."_ For simplicity, I didn't bother to create own masks etc. but you can do this very easy by masking. A mask, white where the glass is and black for emission. Plug this in _Transmission_ - that's it. But did you try emission on glass? A bright emission won't look very transparent even though it's glass.

Comment: Sigh, I just can't seem to get it right. Idk if I'm just doing something dumb, or missing something. Thanks for help anyway, I appreciate the time. Maybe I'll try experimenting a little bit, and if still nothing I'll just forget about it. I don't wanna keep using up your time, so thanks again.

Comment: @WolfStix This is just a wild guess, but is it possible that you don't know how to build materials with different properties for certain areas by mixing and masking? I would really  suggest you do some tutorials on materials and texturing. No offense.

Comment: I'm definitely not the best at it. I'd say I'm in a bit of the starting to know what it does and how to work it sometimes. But when it's stuff like this material I'm trying to make here, it throws me off. This is the closest I've gotten to making this effect, so I'm not sure where to go from here even with some of the tutorials. Not sure if it can help recreate it, but in time in learning maybe something can pop up on what I was missing. Again thanks for your help.